# How can i continue scrolling even if i touch progressBar thumb

Tags: flutter, dart, progress-bar

i have the following code

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
    return ProgressBar()
  },
);
```

Now if i want to scroll in my list but my finger touch the thumb progress it will not scroll

i am struggling with this issue because all my list items is `ProgressBars` and i need to scroll by swiping in screen border to avoid touching the thumb . but How can i make the thumb mush smart so I can scroll smoothly if I touch it by an accident

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the ProgressBar with IgnorePointer and set ignoring to true

```
IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: true,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
            return ProgressBar();
          },
        );,
    ),
```

Comment: thanks , but it will also disable the thumb from seeking !